# win32 bitmaps flashing when more than one sprite on screen

Tags: winapi, bitmap, transparency, sprite, bitblt

I've been using the win32 api to make a game with sprites. For some reason when I have more than one sprite on screen they flash occasionally as if they are disappearing and returning. When there is only one sprite on screen it displays correctly.

I am using C++, win32 API and working with Visual Studio 08

The following is roughly what I have:

```
//creates rect based on window client area
GetClientRect(ghwnd, &screenRect);  
// Initialises front buffer device context (window)
frontHDC = GetDC(ghwnd);    
// sets up Back DC to be compatible with the front  
backHDC = CreateCompatibleDC(frontHDC);
// Create another hdc to store the bitmap in before the backbuffer
bitmapHDC = CreateCompatibleDC(frontHDC);
//creates bitmap compatible with the front buffer
theOldFrontBitMap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(frontHDC, screenRect.right, screenRect.bottom);
//creates bitmap compatible with the back buffer
theOldBackBitMap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(backHDC, theOldFrontBitMap);

HBITMAP originalBitMap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(bitmapHDC,bitmap);

//Transparency function
TransparentBlt( backHDC,
                m_Position.x,
                m_Position.y,
                m_Size.x,
                m_Size.y,
                bitmapHDC,
                0,
                0,
                m_Size.x,
                m_Size.y,
                0x00FFFFFF);

SelectObject(bitmapHDC,originalBitMap);

BitBlt(frontHDC, screenRect.left, screenRect.top, 
       screenRect.right, screenRect.bottom, backHDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

Am I doing this correctly? and if so where am I going wrong? If I have not given enough information please tell me and I will rectify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with creating a Win32 game is that, even if you use double buffering, you have no way to wait for the vertical retrace of the monitor to display the buffer.

Displaying the buffer or sprite while the vertical retrace is in progress can cause tearing or even the disappearing sprite that you experience.

The only real way around this is to use an SDK like OpenGL or DirectX to manage and display the buffers.

Here's a sample program that may help you, use the arrow keys to move the white box on the double buffered background:

```
#include <Windows.h>

RECT rcSize;
HDC hdcBackBuffer, hdcSprite;
HBITMAP hbmBackBuffer, hbmSprite;
int spriteX = 175, spriteY = 175;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HDC hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);

            // make back buffer
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcSize);
            hdcBackBuffer = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);
            hbmBackBuffer = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcBackBuffer, rcSize.right - rcSize.left, rcSize.bottom - rcSize.top);
            SelectObject(hdcBackBuffer, hbmBackBuffer);  // SHOULD SAVE PREVIOUS...

            // make sprite
            hdcSprite = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);
            hbmSprite = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSprite, 50, 50);
            SelectObject(hdcSprite, hbmSprite);  // SHOULD SAVE PREVIOUS...
            RECT rcSprite;
            SetRect(&rcSprite, 0, 0, 50, 50);
            FillRect(hdcSprite, &rcSprite, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));

            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow);
            return 0;
        }
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            // SHOULD REALLY USE GetAsyncKeyState for game, but simplified here
            switch (wParam)
            {
            case VK_LEFT:
                spriteX--;
                break;
            case VK_RIGHT:
                spriteX++;
                break;
            case VK_UP:
                spriteY--;
                break;
            case VK_DOWN:
                spriteY++;
                break;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        {
            return 1; // INDICATE THAT WE ERASED THE BACKGROUND OURSELVES
        }
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // clear back buffer
            FillRect(hdcBackBuffer, &rcSize, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
            // render sprite to back buffer
            BitBlt(hdcBackBuffer, spriteX, spriteY, 50, 50, hdcSprite, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            // render back buffer to screen
            BitBlt(ps.hdc, 0, 0, rcSize.right - rcSize.left, rcSize.bottom - rcSize.top, hdcBackBuffer, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            // TODO - DESTROY ALL BITMAPS AND DEVICE CONTEXTS
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
    default:
        {
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, HINSTANCE hInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    static TCHAR className[] = TEXT("GameClass");
    static TCHAR windowName[] = TEXT("A Game");

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInstance, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hIconSm = NULL;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.lpszClassName = className;
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.style = 0;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return 0;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(className, windowName, WS_CAPTION | WS_BORDER | WS_SYSMENU, 0, 0, 400, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hWnd)
        return 0;

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    for (;;)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }

        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: I do not think the problem is related the the vertical retrace but I understand what you're saying. In my search for a solution i've seen countless win32 game tutorials and when I run them they all seem fine. I've never had any problems with it before but I have only used win32 and sprites twice before. I am convinced I am not doing the buffering correctly in some form.

Comment: That causes a different problem called *tearing*, visible on moving objects.  This sounds like a double-buffering problem but it is impossible to tell what the context of this code might be.  Anyhoo, don't do anything in the WM_ERASEBKGND message handler.

Comment: You don't need the front bitmap.  You need two bitmaps.  The back buffer bitmap and the sprite bitmap.  In WM_PAINT you clear the back buffer and draw the sprite onto it.  You then display the back buffer onto the window (i.e. GetDC())

Answer (score 1):

I think your back buffer implementation is wrong although Im not sure exactly where. Try this implementation of a separate back buffer class. I hope it helps.

Here my back buffer class.

```
#ifndef BACKBUFFER_H
#define BACKBUFFER_H

#include <Windows.h>


class BackBuffer
{
public:
    BackBuffer(HWND hWnd, int width, int height);
    ~BackBuffer();

    HDC getDC();

    int width();
    int height();

    void present();

private:
    // Make copy constructor and assignment operator private
    // so client cannot copy BackBuffers.  We do this because
    // this class is not designed to be copied because it
    // is not efficient--copying bitmaps is slow (lots of memory).
    // In addition, most applications will probably only need one
    // BackBuffer anyway.  
    BackBuffer(const BackBuffer& rhs);
    BackBuffer& operator=(const BackBuffer& rhs);
private:
    HWND    mhWnd;
    HDC     mhDC;
    HBITMAP mhSurface;
    HBITMAP mhOldObject;
    int     mWidth;
    int     mHeight;
};


#endif //BACKBUFFER_H
```

Heres the implementation:

```
BackBuffer::BackBuffer(HWND hWnd, int width, int height)
{
    //Save a copy of the main window handle
    mhWnd = hWnd;

    //Get a handle to the device context associated with
    // the window
    HDC hWndDC = GetDC(hWnd);

    //Save the backbuffer dimensions
    mWidth = width;
    mHeight = height;

    //Create system memory device context that is compatible
    //with the window one
    mhDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hWndDC);

    //Create the backbuffer surface bitmap that is compatible
    //with the window device context bitmap format. That is
    //the surface we will render onto.
    mhSurface = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hWndDC, width, height);

    //Done with DC
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hWndDC);

    //At this point, the back buffer surface is uninitialized,
    //so lets clear it to some non-zero value. Note that it 
    //needs to be a non-zero. If it is zero then it will mess 
    //up our sprite blending logic.

    //Select the backbuffer bitmap into the DC
    mhOldObject = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(mhDC, mhSurface);

    //Select a white brush
    HBRUSH white = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    HBRUSH oldBrush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(mhDC, white);

    //Clear the backbuffer rectangle
    Rectangle(mhDC, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);

    //Restore the original brush
    SelectObject(mhDC, oldBrush);

}

BackBuffer::~BackBuffer()
{
    SelectObject(mhDC, mhOldObject);
    DeleteObject(mhSurface);
    DeleteDC(mhDC);
}

HDC BackBuffer::getDC()
{
    return mhDC;
}

int BackBuffer::width()
{
    return mWidth;
}

int BackBuffer::height()
{
    return mHeight;
}

void BackBuffer::present()
{
    //Get a handle to the device context associated with 
    //the window
    HDC hWndDC = GetDC(mhWnd);

    //Copy the backbuffer contents over to the
    //window client area
    BitBlt(hWndDC, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, mhDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    //Free window DC when done
    ReleaseDC(mhWnd, hWndDC);
}
```

Try to work your way through this implementation the comments should help you understand. Hope this helps.